# How to cut a string backward in Java?

Tags: java, string, cut

I would like to cut my string from backward.

Example:

```
abcdefghijk
```

Output:

```
efghijk
```

(I need only last 7 character of a string.)

Comment: Have you tried `subString()`?

Comment: `string.replaceAll(".*(.{7})$", "$1");`

Comment: String value = "abcdefghijk";
String result = value.substring(4);
System.out.print(result);

Answer (score 0):

You can use, method substring of String: [String.substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

```
string.substring(string.length()-7)
```